# Row number of last empty cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to search throug a column in a Google Spreadsheet with Google Script to find the first empty cell. I will then use the row number of that cell as a variable to input data in a function.

Can anyone help me find the first empty cell in a specific column?

I have tried google, but with no luck.

EDIT:

I found a solution that worked for me. I'm posting it here so if anyone else is looking for a soulution, they will have a starting point.

```
   var dokument = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //In my example I needed to set some offsets
  var offset = 9;
  //The column to be read
  var kolonne = 7;
  var lrow = dokument.getLastRow();
  //Sets offset and looks in the right column
  var range = dokument.getRange(offset, kolonne, lrow-offset, 1);
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) 
  {     
    if (data[i][0] == '') 
    {   
       data[i][0] = i+offset;      
       break;
    }  
  }
```

You can then use the value of the row with

```
  var example = data[i][0];
```

Comment: You didn't search very well, the highest vote score with google apps script tag is precisely about this subject!!!!

Comment: I did see that thread, and tried to get the script to work for me. Unfortunately that example only posted the information from the cell, and not row number which I was looking for. I found a solution, se my updated post.

Comment: You should start from the end in case there is an empty cell in your column. About the script in ref that returns the value in the last row in a column, it also returns the row index implicitly of course!!!  Just return lastRow-1 without the value[] and you're done...

Answer (score 0):

No api for that. Getlastrow will get you the last row with data among all columns not just one.
The only way is to get the entire column and manually search it. If its many rows you can do binary search assuming there are no holes in the data.

Comment: Okay, then I will have to search the entire column. There are not many rows, max 30. Do you have any examples that can get me startet?

Comment: With 100 rows or less just use a for loop on the array of data